# Spring image, form values and list of objects in FormData

Tags: javascript, java, spring, multipartform-data, form-data

I have RestController endpoint:

```
Mono<A> editA(@PathVariable String id, @Valid A a)
```

Class A looks like that:

```
class A {
  private MultipartFile imageToSave;
  private String name;
  private String otherString;
  private ArrayList<B> bList;
}
```

Class B looks similar like class A (but contains just String fiels).

Frontend client(React using Axios) sends form values (two strings, image file). I use javascript FormData object to send this values into one request and it was working fine.

But i also want to send a list B object. So I tried just add a list B objects to FormData and send it.

How i can send list with object using FormData and them map it to ArrayList ?

> Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'a' on field 'bList': rejected value
>   [[object Object]]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.a.bList,typeMismatch.bList,typeMismatch.java.util.ArrayList,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [a.bList,bList]; arguments []; default message
>   [bList]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.ArrayList' for property
>   'bList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.util.ArrayList' for property 'bList': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found]]

Comment: From this exception, it looks like the JSON the app is receiving, contains a string instead an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar kind of error while passing error using formData in laravel. Turns out you cant use the formData API with the arrays. 
Have a look at the following url : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
It only accepts string or blob.
For your solution, you will have to something like what I did.

```
  let formData = {};
            for (var property in this.form) {
                if (this.form.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                      //  formData.append(property,this.form[property]);
                        formData[property] = this.form[property];

                }
            }
```

Here what I am doing is essentially just building object from the forms input properties and then using the below code passing through axios.

```
axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url
                    data : formData,
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                }).then((response) => { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me.